# iOS - Dismiss UIDatePicker presented as inputView

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uidatepicker, inputview

I have a text field in my UI that when it's selected presents a UIDatePicker instead of the default keyboard, how could I set up a button as to dismiss the picker when the user is done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I do is have my inputView as a custom view which contains a `UIDatePicker` and a toolbar above it with a 'Done' button wired up to a method that calls a delegate method to tell the object that owns the `UITextField` to dismiss the "keyboard" by calling `resignFirstResponder`.

Comment: Mind providing some code for setting up the UIBarButtonItem on the UIToolBar?

Comment: @8vius - that's really not the question here. If you really need help with that I suggest reading the docs for `UIBarButtonItem` and `UIToolbar` and if you're still stuck, ask another question.

Comment: @mattjgalloway I do this way, but calling `resignFirstResponder` does not bring the custom input view keyboard down

Comment: @onmyway133 if you use `textField.inputView = datePicker`, you can then use `view.endEditing(_:)` to dismiss the "keyboard" (which in this case is the UIDatePicker)

Answer (score 1):

Create a UIView (namely customDatePickerView) and in that view ,create datepicker and a done button and a cancel button  in the xib.
In the textfield delegate:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == textfieldName) {
        [textfieldName resignFirstResponder];
         //show the view
         self.customDatePickerView.hidden = NO;

    }

}//dismisses keyboard
```

Function on Date Picker Value Changed

```
- (IBAction)onDatePickerClick:(id)sender {

    NSDateFormatter  *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"];
    NSDate *selectedDate = [self.wellRecordDatePicker date];
    NSString *recordDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:selectedDate];
    self.yourTextfieldName.text = recordDate;


}

- (IBAction)onDoneBtnClick:(id)sender
{
       self.customDatePickerView.hidden = YES;
}
- (IBAction)onCancelBtnClick:(id)sender
{
       self.customDatePickerView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a similar thing where I've created a view with a button and the `UIDatePicker`, then presented that view instead of the `UIDatePicker` alone. Then the button is just connected to an `IBAction` that moves the view out.

This way, the button moves in with the `UIDatePicker` view and they look "connected" to the user. You can even define this `UIView` in your nib and use `addSubview:` at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by adding this

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Add this where you want to dismiss date picker like i have added this on tap gesture
On viewDidLoad added a Tapgesture

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *gesRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)]; // Declare the Gesture.
    gesRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesRecognizer];
```

After adding this on viewdidLoad  Add this method to detect gesture recognizer

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    NSLog(@"Tapped");
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```